# Need dotJEM/Angular-Routing Help - View won't update with new template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to figure out why the first time I come to the "audit" state the "audit.content" execute; but subsequent calls to "audit" state from the "audit" update my "audit.content" view.

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Here are the details of my dotJEM/Angular-Routing:

I have an index file that has a jemView in it like so:

```
<div jem-view="main.content"></div>
```

I have a new-audit-view.html page that has two nested jemViews in it like so:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div jem-view="audit.actions">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div jem-view="audit.content">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my application.js file:

```
angular.module('OReillyAutoPricingWebApp',
[
    'dotjem.routing'
])
// Configuration of the routes for linking to different view of the application.
.config(['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($stateProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/audit-review-tab' });

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', { route: '/', views: { 'main.content': { template: 'views/review-audits.html'} } })
        .state('audit', { route: '/audit/:auditItemListType', views: {
            'main.content': {template: 'views/new-audit-view.html'},
            'audit.actions': {template: 'partials/audit-action-items.html', controller: 'StoreAuditItemController'},
            'audit.content': {template: ['$location', function ($location) {
                var resourceLoader = new NoesisCode.ResourceLoader(),
                    partialUrl = ($location.search().url !== undefined)? $location.search().url: "",
                    templateHtml = ($location.search().url !== undefined)? resourceLoader.loadXMLDoc(partialUrl): "";

                return templateHtml;
            }], controller: 'StoreAuditItemController'}}
        })
        .state('audits', { route: '/audits', views: { 'main.content': { template: 'views/review-audits.html'} } })
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to add the $transitionProvider service to the configuration. And then implement the transition like so:

```
$stateTransitionProvider
        .transition('*', 'audit', function ($view){
            $view.clear('audit.content');
            $view.update('audit.content', {template: ['$location', function ($location) {
                var resourceLoader = new NoesisCode.ResourceLoader(),
                    partialUrl = ($location.search().url !== undefined)? $location.search().url: "",
                    templateHtml = ($location.search().url !== undefined)? resourceLoader.loadXMLDoc(partialUrl): "";
                console.info("inside audit.content view");

                return templateHtml;
            }], controller: 'StoreAuditItemController'});
        });
```